# Appending an object in JSON using jq which is triggered by shell with run time arguments

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I am trying to insert objects into JSON file using a shell which contains a jq

Here is the script shell.sh

```
#/bin/sh!
cp -f test.json test.json.tmp
jq '.cores |= . + {"brand3": "{", "master_url": "http://master.solr.local:8983/solr/brand3", "poll_interval": "00:01:00"}' test.json.tmp >test.json
rm test.json.tmp
```

test.json file

```
 {
  "cores": {
    "brand1-nl-nl-live": {
      "master_url": "http://master.solr.local:8983/solr/brand1-nl-nl-live",
      "poll_interval": "00:01:00"
    },
    "brand2-nl-nl-live": {
      "master_url": "http://master.solr.local:8983/solr/brand2-nl-nl-live",
      "poll_interval": "00:01:00"
    },
 "brand3-nl-nl-live": "{",
    "master_url": "http://master.solr.local:8983/solr/brand3-nl-nl-live",
    "poll_interval": "00:01:00"
  }
}
```

Which is working but don't want with quotes and comma "{",

Next step is I will be running shell with runtime argumnts command (./shell.sh brand3-nl-nl-live)

Example:

```
#/bin/sh!

var=$1
cp -f test.json test.json.tmp
jq '.cores |= . + {"$var": "{", "master_url": "http://master.solr.local:8983/solr/$var", "poll_interval": "00:01:00"}' test.json.tmp >test.json
rm test.json.tmp
```

which should insert the object in json

```
 {
  "cores": {
    "brand1-nl-nl-live": {
      "master_url": "http://master.solr.local:8983/solr/brand1-nl-nl-live",
      "poll_interval": "00:01:00"
    },
    "brand2-nl-nl-live": {
      "master_url": "http://master.solr.local:8983/solr/brand2-nl-nl-live",
      "poll_interval": "00:01:00"
    },
 "brand3-nl-nl-live": {
    "master_url": "http://master.solr.local:8983/solr/brand3-nl-nl-live",
    "poll_interval": "00:01:00"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add an argument as key of an object you must do it this way:

```sh
jq --arg v $1 '.cores[$v] = { master_url: "http://master.solr.local:8983/solr/$var", poll_interval: "00:01:00"}' test.json.tmp > test.json
```

So change your script to:

```sh
#/bin/sh!

var=$1
cp -f test.json test.json.tmp
jq --arg v $1 '.cores[$v] = { master_url: "http://master.solr.local:8983/solr/$var", poll_interval: "00:01:00"}'  test.json.tmp >test.json
rm test.json.tmp
```

and run it this way: `./yourscript.sh mykey`

Comment: Thanks Key is replaced , But $var is not replaced by arguement.
heres is output : 
http://master.solr.local:8983/solr/$var

Comment: tried this 
master.solr.local:8983/solr/'$var'

It worked 
thank you for the help :)